# local apt-mirror says Release cant be found, but its there, what am i missing

Tags: server, apt, 16.04

running apt-get update on a host thats pointing at my local mirror returns the following warnings and errors...

```
W: The repository 'https://apt.devita.co/puppet xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.devita.co/puppet/dists/xenial/PC1/binary-amd64/Packages
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

you can see screenshots of the local repo here, and the repo is publically available temporarily while I troubleshoot.

[image]
[image]

my sources.list.d looks like this

```
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# puppetlabs-pc1
deb https://apt.devita.co/puppet xenial PC1 main
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# xenial-backports
deb https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# xenial
deb https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# xenial-security
deb https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# xenial-updates
deb https://apt.devita.co/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

and the `/var/www` dir is symlinks to the apt-mirror locations like so
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been discussing this on IRC in `#ubuntu-server`. So far it looks like a CA added to `/etc/ssl/certs` broke update-ca-certificates, so `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` was broken or just empty, so `apt-transport-https` wasn't working at all.

Debugged using: `apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::https=1 update`

Comment: this ended up being it, going to http:// internally fixes the issue, and thats fine since externally we arent using it.